# Why does this keep returning a tie?

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript to build a Rock Paper Scissors game that keeps score. Why does this keep returning a tie? Also do you see any problems with my code for keeping score? Will this be easy to save the score variables to localStorage? I've also added my HTML on the bottom.

```js
var userChoice = document.getElementById("selection").value;
var totalScore = document.getElementById("score");
var yourScore = 0
var compScore = 0
var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper"; 
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        alert( "It's a tie.");
    }
    if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            alert("You lose")
            compScore += 1
            totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore
        }
      if (choice2 === "paper") {
          alert("you win")
          yourScore += 1
          totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore

     }

 }
    if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            alert("You Win.")
            yourScore += 1
            totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore
        }
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            alert("You lose.")
            compScore += 1
            totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore

        }
  }
    if (choice1 ==="rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            alert("You win.")
            yourScore += 1 
            totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore
        }
        if (choice2 === "paper") {
            alert("You lose.")
            compScore += 1
            totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore

        }
    }
  }
  compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <input type="text" id="selection">
  <button onclick="compare()">Play</button>
  <h1 id="score">The Score is 0-0</h1>
</html>
```

Comment: please add your HTML file too

Comment: Its at the bottom of the code. Sorry I don't know how to make it two separate snippets

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

There are a few issues here:

1. You are retrieving the user input when the page is loaded (when your script is loaded) instead of when the button is pressed.
2. You are not passing any values into the compare function when the button is pressed.  You are calling "compare()" instead of "compare(value1, value2)"
3. The computerChoice is not being reset after each game.  This isn't really a bug as it is just an issue with gameplay.

Here's a fiddle that shows it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lrbh8n3j/

And here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <input type="text" id="selection">
 <button onclick="doCompare()">Play</button>
 <h1 id="score">The Score is 0-0</h1>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var totalScore = document.getElementById("score");
var yourScore = 0
var compScore = 0

  var doCompare = function() {
     var userChoice = document.getElementById("selection").value;
      var computerChoice = Math.random();
      if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
          computerChoice = "rock";
      } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
          computerChoice = "paper"; 
      } else {
          computerChoice = "scissors";
      }

         return compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
  }

  var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
      if(choice1 === choice2) {
          alert( "It's a tie.");
      }
    if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            alert("You lose")
            compScore += 1
            totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore
        }
      if (choice2 === "paper") {
          alert("you win")
          yourScore += 1
          totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore

     }

 }
    if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            alert("You Win.")
            yourScore += 1
            totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore
        }
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            alert("You lose.")
            compScore += 1
            totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore

        }
  }
    if (choice1 ==="rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors"){
            alert("You win.")
            yourScore += 1 
            totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore
        }
        if (choice2 === "paper") {
            alert("You lose.")
            compScore += 1
            totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore

        }
    }
  }
 </script>
 </html>
```

Comment: How do I retrieve after the button is pressed, and do you have any ideas for how to reset computerChoice? Thank you for your help

Comment: Please see my updated answer with code.  Everything is fixed there. :)  I added a new function "doCompare" that grabs the user input and recalculates the computer choice when the button is clicked.

Comment: dakben, if this didn't work, please let me know.  If it did, I'd apprecite my answer being marked as correct.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The onclick handler calls the compare function which requires two arguments which you aren't passing to the function. You don't need any parameters to the function, instead move this line inside the function `var userChoice = document.getElementById("selection").value;` and then create a function that generates the computers choice inside the compare function `var computerChoice = getComputerMove()`

Answer (score 0):

You must check `input` on `button`'s click. So first enter something into input, then click the button & see it working. I have made

```js
var totalScore = document.getElementById("score");
var yourScore = 0;
var compScore = 0;
var computerChoice = Math.random();
console.log(computerChoice);
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
  computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
  computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
  computerChoice = "scissors";
}
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    console.log("It's a tie.");
  }
  if (choice1 === "scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
      console.log("You lose");
      compScore += 1;
      totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore;
    }
    if (choice2 === "paper") {
      console.log("you win");
      yourScore += 1;
      totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore;
    }
  }
  if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
      console.log("You Win.");
      yourScore += 1;
      totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore;
    }
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
      console.log("You lose.");
      compScore += 1;
      totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore;
    }
  }
  if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
      console.log("You win.");
      yourScore += 1;
      totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore;
    }
    if (choice2 === "paper") {
      console.log("You lose.");
      compScore += 1;
      totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore;
    }
  }
};

totalScore.addEventListener('click', function() {
 var userChoice = document.getElementById("selection").value;
 compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
})
```

```html
<input id="selection" />
<button id="score">Score</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
  var totalScore = document.getElementById("score");
  var yourScore = 0
  var compScore = 0

  var computerChoice = function() {
    val = Math.random();
    if (val < 0.34) {
      return "rock";
    }
    return computerChoice <= 0.67 ? "paper" : "scissors";
  }

  var compare = function() {
    choice1 = document.getElementById("selection").value;
        choice2 = computerChoice();

    if (choice1 === choice2) {
      alert("It's a tie.");
    }
    if (choice1 === "scissors") {
      if (choice2 === "rock") {
        alert("You lose")
        compScore += 1
        totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore
      }
      if (choice2 === "paper") {
        alert("you win")
        yourScore += 1
        totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore

      }

    }
    if (choice1 === "paper") {
      if (choice2 === "rock") {
        alert("You Win.")
        yourScore += 1
        totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore
      }
      if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        alert("You lose.")
        compScore += 1
        totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore

      }
    }
    if (choice1 === "rock") {
      if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        alert("You win.")
        yourScore += 1
        totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore
      }
      if (choice2 === "paper") {
        alert("You lose.")
        compScore += 1
        totalScore.innerHTML = "The score is " + yourScore + " - " + compScore

      }
    }
  }
```